# Multiple threads to run for a period of time

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

In an application, I'm sending a set of data to a class A which should actually sleep for a certain period of time and send the data back. There are multiple classes that use class A. So, there are multiple threads for each set of data. 
Say for example, data A needs to sleep for time 10 seconds and then return. At the same time, there can be data B with time 20 seconds that it needs to wait before returning. So, time values is linked to data. What is the best possible way to do this?
My application uses `Swing`. Can I use `Swing Timers`/`Swing Workers` for this? (I might have to do a little data check before returning). Or should I use normal threads to run this and how?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Can you give some sort of attempt or base to work off of? You're saying you're sending data to a `class A`, which that `class A` should sleep, then send the data back? Only a `Thread` can sleep. If you want a `Thread` to compute data, then `return` something, you're gonna want to look into `Callable`

Comment: @VinceEmigh Yeah i understand. Actually, its a prototype, no code! So, trying to understand which is the best way to do it? What I meant was, class A can create multiple threads inside to do the work. So, I have an option to use Swing Timers / Workers or probably create a thread pool?

Comment: You say this is a prototype. I assume this means that the sleeping is just there to simulate the delay for the actual work that will come later. If that's the case, then it would be better to use something like a thread pool since that's what you'll need later if you actually want to process multiple batches of data at the same time.

Comment: @Mercenary as DoaWen said, you should use a Thread Pool instead of trying to create your own thread handling system. `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` will create Threads when needed, but, if there are Threads sitting idle, they will be re-used. It would be better if you were to tell us what you are actually attempting, rather than giving examples. There are times where SwingWorkers are good for sending full methods to the `EDT`, and there are times where it's better to handle synchronizing yourself. It seems like you need to look more into multiple threads interacting with the same values.